# UIStepper Not Visible

Tags: ios, uistepper

Via storyboard in XCode 5.0.1, I've added a simple UIStepper in my ViewController.  However, I've noticed that when I place it up towards the top of my screen where I need it it doesn't actually appear in the simulator nor on the device.  I thought I was going crazy so I created a test app outside of my regular working project to prove I wasn't--as it turns out, I'm not.  I placed it in a simple view and noticed the bottom edge of it up at the very top of the view.  (I wasn't seeing it at all in my original project because I had a nav-bar at the top.)

The following images show it as it appears in the storyboard (UIStepper visible) and on the simulator/device:

[image]
(Storyboard)

[image]
(Simulator)

Two questions:  Is this a bug?  Other than guessing where it should appear and setting its frame origin manually what would be the recommended approach to ensuring my UIStepper shows up as I've placed it in the storyboard?   (I'm afraid manually setting the frame origin would break or mis-align in future iOS versions.)

Comment: Are you using auto layout? If so, what are your constraints?

Comment: Nope, no autolayout.  Trying to be backwards compatible to 5.1